# Why does nasm say "invalid combination of opcode and oprands"?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to assemble a certain file of code in which nasm points to a line (shown below) and says "invalid combination of opcode and oprands". I have no idea what's wrong with the line.

```
out edx,ecx
```

The line of code sends the address in ecx to port 0xCF8 - the value in edx.

Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`out` has two forms, `out <imm8>, al/ax/eax` and `out dx, al/ax/eax`. Your instruction matches neither of these, so it is malformed.

Change your code such that the value you want is in `eax` instead of `ecx` (which might be as easy as `mov eax, ecx`) and use the second form.

Assembler messages are often inadequate, so get your hands on an instruction reference.

Comment: I changed it to out edx,eax and I still get the same error.